I got the error "Failed host lookup" in Flutter project
I got the error "Failed host lookup" in Flutter project.
My code is
class HttpApi {

  static const _domain = 'xxx.com';

  static const _timeout = 60;

  static final client = HttpClient();
  static final _http = IOClient(client);

  static Future<Response> apiGet(
    String path, [
    bool needToken = false,
    bool isApiInfo = false,
  ]) async {
    final urlBase = isApiInfo ? _domain : Global().apiDomain;
    final url = Uri.parse(urlBase + path);
    final headers = await _createTokenHeaderks(needToken);
    final res = await _http.get(url, headers: headers).timeout(
      const Duration(seconds: _timeout),
      onTimeout: () {
        throw TimeoutException('Timeout error in apiGet.');
      },
    );
    _log(res, null);
    return _handleResponse(res);
  }

  static Future<Response> apiPost(
    String urls,
    Map<String, dynamic>? body, [
    bool needToken = false,
  ]) async {
    final url = Uri.parse(Global().apiDomain + urls);
    final jsonBody = body != null ? jsonEncode(body) : null;
    final headers = await _createTokenHeaders(needToken);
    final res = await _http.post(url, headers: headers, body: jsonBody).timeout(
          const Duration(seconds: _timeout),
          onTimeout: () => throw TimeoutException('Timeout error in apiPost.'),
        );
    _log(res, body);
    return _handleResponse(res);
  }


I got the error "Exception has occurred. _ClientSocketException (Failed host lookup: 'xxx.com')"
It looks URL is wrong but actually not.
Any possiblity mistake in code?
I tried to change URL some pattern but all doesn't work.

did you add  , if this is an android project.

Does this answer your question? How to solve SocketException: Failed host lookup: 'www.xyz.com' (OS Error: No address associated with hostname, errno = 7)

make sure the following: calling a correct URL, have an internet access, have an internet access permission

You mean in AndroidManifest.xml? Yes I added there

Yes I have permission for sure.
